# Invoking Method using BCEL

Tags: java, methods, bytecode, bcel

is there any expert in this community who have worked with BCEL and can guide me about **invocation of method using BCEL** *just like we use to do with java reflection.*

Note:to support your answer any sort of book or web reference will become a great source of help.

Now i have seen a interface named [Visitor](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/generic/Visitor)  containing method **visitInvokeInstruction()** 
Now is there a way so that i can invoke these instruction(that formed a method on stack).

Hope this piece of code give u people a lot of explanation what i want.

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure if such a way exists it will use reflection internally, so why not use it in the first place?

Comment: I am looking at your code, looks like you are writing a proxy class that measures the time needed for method execution in the proxied class, am I correct?.

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos, yes u r quit right but this code is incomplete and it does not execute the method that's the key probelm i need to solve out

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use BCELifier, a class that comes with BCEL that takes a classfile and emits source code that uses BCEL to emit that classfile - essentially it decompiles the classfile not into bytecodes or the original Java source, but the BCEL code required to emit that.

In your case, just write a simple, dummy class that contains the code you want to produce, then run BCELifier and check the results.

Comment: can you give any small example to support your answer kindly

Comment: @zaree - [BCELifier](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/10/22/bcel.html?page=2)

Comment: @McDowell your link elaborate BCEL quit positively,BUT all the same there is nothing on invoking a method.I will post some code kindly view it and then gave me some more guidelines